# Python: Generate weekly timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix, timestamp

How can I generate weekly timestamps in Python?

I want something that looks like this:

```
2021-01-07 12:00:00
2021-01-14 12:00:00
2021-01-21 12:00:00
etc...
```

I also want to convert these to UNIX timestamps.

Is there a way to do all this in one step?

Thank you!

Comment: `pd.date_range("2021-01-07", "2021-01-21", freq="7D").to_numpy().astype("datetime64[s]").astype("int")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

```py
pd.date_range('2021-01-07 12:00:00', '2021-01-21 12:00:00', freq='7D')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas works well, but instead of adding an extra dependency, you can also use `datetime` which was created for this purpose and doesn't require conversion of timestamps. On my computer, it is roughly 20x faster before conversion from the `pandas` format.

See this example on how to use it:

```
import datetime

noon_today = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(12, 0))
one_week = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
for i in range(3):
    print(noon_today + i * one_week)
```